# Changing Default 'state' field in state_machine Gem to something Custom

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using StateMachine Gem in one of my Rails App. Before i started using StateMachine my Model had a field named :state (Country's State). As StateMachine initialises on :state.
My model show conflict & doesn't let it save.
Is there any way i can change the name of default field to initialise StateMachine

Something like

```
state_machine initial: :scheduled, *field :custom_state* do
  # state details
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after searching/experimenting for a long time.I figured you can simply do.

```
state_machine initial: :scheduled, attribute: :<yourField> do
  # state details
end
```